# Generate new IAM password for new HikariCP connections

Tags: java, spring-boot, amazon-iam, datasource, hikaricp

I have a Spring Boot (2.3.5.RELEASE) with Spring Cloud (Hoxton.RELEASE) project that I am trying to set up my DataSource for.

I am able to get my Hikari Connection Pool set up, but I use IAM tokens for the database password, and those expire every 15 minutes. How can I set my DataSource so that a new token is generated for new connections that are opened up after the connection pool is started up (I can generate a token for the initial connections, just not any that are opened after the token expires).

I have set the max lifetime for connections to well over the 15 minutes (I have tested up to 4 hours so far) and the connections work as long as they are open. However, once a new connection is created, it just uses the initial password that was generated at startup.

My current config:

```
@Configuration
public class DBConfig {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DBConfig.class);

    private static final String SESSION_NAME = "db.session";

    private static final int CONNECTION_IDLE_TIMEOUT = 1800000;     // Idle for 30 minutes max
    private static final int CONNECTION_KEEP_ALIVE_TIME = 60000;    // Ensure connection is alive every minute
    private static final int CONNECTION_MAX_LIFETIME = 14400000;    // Keep connections alive for 4 hours, then refresh
    private static final int CONNECTION_TOKEN_REFRESH = CONNECTION_MAX_LIFETIME - 300000; // Refresh token every 3 hr 55 minutes

    @Value("${db.name}")
    private String dbName;

    @Value("${db.host}")
    private String host;

    @Value("${db.port}")
    private String port;

    @Value("${db.username}")
    private String username;

    @Value("${db.region}")
    private String awsRegion;

    @Value("${aws.role.arn}")
    private String awsRoleArn;

    @Bean(name = "getDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource")
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        logger.info("Setting DataSource connection with " + this);

        try {
            HikariConfig hikariConfig = new HikariConfig();

            hikariConfig.setDataSource(IAMUtils.setDataSource(awsRegion, host, Integer.parseInt(port), dbName, username, awsRoleArn, SESSION_NAME));

            hikariConfig.setIdleTimeout(CONNECTION_IDLE_TIMEOUT);
            hikariConfig.setMaxLifetime(CONNECTION_MAX_LIFETIME);
            hikariConfig.setKeepaliveTime(CONNECTION_KEEP_ALIVE_TIME);

            return new HikariDataSource(hikariConfig);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Unable to set up DataSource: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    /*
    @Scheduled(fixedRate = CONNECTION_MAX_LIFETIME, initialDelay = CONNECTION_TOKEN_REFRESH)
    public void refreshedRDSToken() {
        HikariDataSource datasource = (HikariDataSource) getDataSource();
        HikariConfigMXBean hikariConfigMXBean = datasource.getHikariConfigMXBean();

        logger.info(String.format("Refreshing IAM Auth tokens in " + hikariConfigMXBean.getPoolName()));
        hikariConfigMXBean.setPassword(IAMUtil.getIAMAuthToken(awsRegion, auroraHost, Integer.parseInt(auroraPort), auroraUsername,
                awsRoleArn, SESSION_NAME));

        HikariPoolMXBean pool = datasource.getHikariPoolMXBean();
        if (pool != null) {
            pool.softEvictConnections();  // Close unused connections & mark open ones for disposal
            pool.resumePool();    // Re-enable connections
        }
    }
    */
}
```

I currently have my scheduler commented out, but I am able to use that to generate new tokens and then set up new connections. However, I don't want to do that every 14 minutes, and the way it currently is set up is to do it every 3 hr 55 min. But if new connections are needed to be set up between the initial 15 minutes and the token refresh, those won't work.

How can I just "set" a new password when a new connection is being made. Preferable after the initial startup (I can use the initial token for all connections created at startup).

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Did you found a way?

Comment: @GuillermoGarcia - Yes I did, but I am not the biggest fan of the implementation. I would like to use `AwsWrapperDataSource` but I am having a trouble with my implementation of it. In the meantime, I am overriding the HikariDataSource `getConnection` method, checking if I need to update my token (so once every 15 minutes), and then calling `super.getConnection()`. Again, it is not how I would like to do it in the end, but it works for now.

Comment: Hello @Ebad I have a question on setting up HikariDatasource for enabling RDS IAM token usage. As part of DataSource initialization, it creates a HikariPool and in that it calls a checkFailFast. This function requires username and password to be setup in the beginning to have a quick check if the connection is success. I am not able to find a way to disable this or satisfy this with an initial password (which fails the idea of using IAM token). Have you ever faced this ?

Comment: @Anand You need to generate the IAM token before setting up the HikariPool. So, for example, at the start of the `getDataSource()`, first generate the IAM token, and then use that token as the password when setting up the actual DataSource.

Comment: One more question about overriding `getConnection`. When you find out that its time to update token what are you doing before invoking `super.getConnection()`? Are you generating a new token and setting it as the password? And if that is the case would you need a periodic check? Any time when a connection is requested we could get a new token and update it as the password right?

Comment: @Ebad what is the need to update the token every 15 minutes like a loop check? Evert time when getConnection is called, wont it be enough to refresh it only after checking if the last token was aged more than 15 minutes?

Comment: @Anand For my application, it is likely to get refreshed before the token expires (I actually set it to "expire" after 13 minutes, instead of the actual expiry of 15 minutes). This will typically allow the token to get refreshed (in my use case) before it actually expires, preventing any potential issues that may be caused by trying to use it after it expires. It was more of an "extra precaution" than a necessity. I would assume it should work fine by just checking if it has actually expired and then generating a new one.

Comment: @Ebad I am seeing similar behaviour. I am checking whether the token has expired(a time checker) every time when either getConnection or getPassword is called. If expired, a new token is generated and set in the `getHikariConfigMXBean` password property.